# unsupported operand type(s) for /: ‘map’ and 'int’

Tags: python, django

```
##models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    import numpy as np

    class Wine(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=200)        
        def average_rating(self):
            all_ratings = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all())
            return np.mean(all_ratings)  
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

*Why is this error showing?What is wrong at line 7?*

Comment: If you get an error can you post the complete traceback? I assume numpy doesn't like the map object, try making it into a list via `list(map(...))`.

Comment: thanks @syntonym it worked

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to use numpy for this. You could easily calculate the mean yourself, but why not let the database do it via its aggregation features?

```
from django.db.models import Avg
...
def average_rating(self):
    return self.review_set.aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']
```

Comment: thanks for solution..i made list instead of map and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you: Change

```
return np.mean(all_ratings)
```

to

```
return np.mean(list(all_ratings))
```

It works for me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), `map()` returns an iterable while, in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map), it returns a list. Any mathematical operation, like mean, between a python iterable and an integer would throw similar error. The line:

```
return np.mean(all_ratings)
```

throws the mentioned error in Python 3 as `all_ratings` is an iterable returned by the function `map()`. It is likely that you are working in Python 3. So you need to convert `all_ratings` into list before any mathematical operation, like so, `np.mean(list(all_ratings))`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:-

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import numpy as np

class Wine(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)        
    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = list(map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all()))
        return np.mean(all_ratings)  
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```